# Is there an expression which dictates which form of delete is used (implicite versus complete)?

Tags: python

Let's say I have `class A(<class ...>): pass`. Should I be explicitly calling `del` for a deep delete? Let me be more specific: What happens just before a fork merge with a current thread? When a thread is being interwoven with another, does it thrash or use a pointer?

**EDIT**

Aha! http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `del` keyword doesn't actually explicitly remove an object. It decrements the reference count, and then the garbage collector cleans up the memory if nothing else is using it. It's useful when you have a block of code that will be running for a long time, and a variable that's eating up a lot of memory that you don't need anymore.

Once you exit the scope of a function, all variables will have their reference count decremented (and cleaned up if appropriate). There is nothing *deep* or special about an explicit call to `del`.

Oh I should also mention that the `del` command removes the variable name from the local scope. So from your point of view the variable is gone. However if other things are referencing the object being pointed to, the memory itself will not be cleaned up (yet).

**EDIT**

Forks don't merge. You can `wait` on a fork to exit, but that's it. And when you `join` another thread, they aren't being merged there either. They have different stacks (but the same heap). When a thread ends, all variables within that thread's scope have their reference count decremented (and cleaned up if appropriate). I don't understand you question about thrashing and pointers -- I have no idea what thrashing means, and python doesn't have pointers.

Comment: @Chris, not linux forks, my process-copied forks. Forks do in fact thread concurrently, or how else would I be running 2+2 cores with 2 channels? Python uses pointers, but you cannot tell them what to do until my question has an answer.

Comment: @Sean: your terminology is wrong. You're doing multi-processing, not multi-threading. When you fork, your processes are forever separate. They may share some memory, but it's a read-only share. As soon as one of them tries to change it, new memory is used. Forks don't merge, they simply die (separate and alone -- kinda depressing). If you want to communicate, you need to use IPC like shared memory or pipes or something.

Comment: @Chris, Please excuse my newness to accurate terminology. My threads are at the Python layer and need to merge. It's the only option that makes sense.

Comment: @Sean: threads or forks? You just said you were using forks, and now it's threads. Python threads are not real threads (only 1 can execute at a time). Neither forks nor threads "merge". Both simply stop executing. In the case of a fork, the memory is lost because the process has terminated. In the case of a thread, you can still access the memory because you share a common heap. However there is no "merging" action of any sort regardless of the concurrency model. Both `wait` and `join` just wait for the other thing to finish.

Comment: @Sean: swapping is handled by the OS, not python. It has nothing to do with which process / thread is currently executing. And the fact that it's a distributed system is neither here nor there. If that's the case I can guarantee you that python (by itself) isn't capable of utilizing its capabilities.

Comment: This is not an answer to any of my questions. Although being informative to readers, it does not communicate any sort of method which operates recycling operations or forces reference counts. Furthermore it fails to define how call stack memory is swapped during multiprocessing. It continues and ends with "doesn't matter", "will not work", et cetera.

Comment: @Sean: this is a waste of my time. You can't stay on topic. You asked about the `del` keyword, and I answered your question. You can't manually clean up memory in Python. Python specifically disallows this because its unsafe (its one of the main features of the language). Reference counts go to zero when nothing is using an object, or the program exits. I'm not concerned with your problems with forking / threading / distributing because that's NOT what you asked. I'm done here.